# How to keep check on null values in Firebase

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Data insertion and extraction are the backbone of every interactive app. The process becomes more complex when the give-take of data has to be done on cloud/Database. A slight negligence can make an app cash.

Consider a sample **Profile.java**

```
public class Profile {
    public String _id;
    public String picture;
    public String name;
    public String phone;
    public String address;
    public List<String> tags;
  
  //Constructors and Getter/Setters
}
```

Normal getter/setter sets the data only if they are called, otherwise, the variable holds null, Suppose we have no tags, we instantiated object and stored it to a database like Firestore. The data when returned would be :

```
{
    "_id": "604dd8a22b33c172afbd3eb5",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "name": "Bradshaw Osborn",
    "phone": "+1 (870) 422-3637",
    "address": "209 Crown Street, Caln, Kansas, 5223",
    "tags": null
  }
```

Since tags are null all list functions on tags would not work, whereas it should have at least been empty.
The normal workaround I found is to check data during instantiating an object through constructors or getter setters like:

```
public Profile(){
//instantiate all variables as empty
tags=new ArrayList<String>()
}
```

this technique ensures data is at least empty before sending it to the database etc.

How to handle such cases, since a large app can easily have >15 model classes, is instantiating all variables to empty states only an option?

Comment: I think you will get a lot of opinion based answers here so here's my take on it. You should create different classes for representing your back end data and your UI data. That way you have the flexibility to implement functionality specific to each one and change either with a minimal impact on the other.

Comment: `is instantiating all variables to empty...` if you're sending null values, then you should expect to get those back. if an api can't give you a value you're expecting, it will be null too. so, not much else to do about this

Comment: So what's the problem, you don't want to have properties like "tags" to hold null values? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I am asking the prefered way to hold null values, Should we assign some empty values to them while the constructor is called, assign default values in getters when the object is filled or check for nulls where objects are being used.

Comment: The preferred way of holding "null" values is to hold them as "null" and always check against nullity when getting data.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yah correct, but when there are 20-30 objects, some nullity checks can be missed causing error. How to manage it at a large scale is my concern.

Comment: In that case, don't add properties with the null value at all.

Comment: @AlexMamo I acknowledge it but in apps, data is added by users and sometimes we can't force users to add all fields example: the address field in Profile. Adding to add some errors can creep in. Hence null values are indicators of errors too. Avoiding it altogether is not an option.

Comment: Then simply use "null", if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you could either declare the field as

```java
public List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or you could update the getter method like:

```java
return (tags != null) ? tags : Collections.emptyList();
```

But rather than initializing the list in all cases, we could initialize only when some data is to be added to the list.

```java
public List<String> tags;

public void addTag(String tag) {
    if(tags == null) {
        tags = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    tags.add(tag);
}
```

Comment: `we could initialize only when some data is to be added to the list` i don't think the last part of your answer is actually relevant here, because OP will be getting data from an api it seems

Comment: @a_local_nobody Maybe if the current data is first retrieved and then tags are updated based on some conditions and then another API is invoked to update the data. In such a case this could be a possible scenario right?

Comment: yes, but it seems like OP is asking about how to deal with this type of problem when the data is retrieved/sent and i don't really think there is a way of dealing with it, except initializing values when declared. either way, not my question and i have no real problem with your answer either, just a comment :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody OP states that `all list functions on tags would not work`. It is not clear from the question what those operations are, I thought updating the data could be one of them.